# Adding field to attribute table distorts existing columns using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table

I am using ArcMap 10.6.

I am intending to add a new field to the attribute table of a shapefile containing polylines in ArcMap. I started by loading the shapefile and opened the attribute table where I added a new field via Table Options - Add Field  (datatype Double).

This adding of a new field somehow leads to the existing columns of the type Double to be altered. In the image added to the post you can see that the values of the column "year" move one column to the right and now populate the column "Km". The values of "Km" went into "Unit" where they are not merged with the original values of "Unit". Furthermore, in "CO2" there are now values of unknown origin.

I received the concerned shapefile from someone else and guess this behaviour has something to do with the way it was created. How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a workaround. I exported the shapefile into a geodatabase. After loading the resulting feature-class to my map I was able to add fields to the attribut table without affecting the existing columns. I still do not know what was wrong with the shapefile in the first place though.

Comment: In the future you might remove any index (sbn and sbx) files in the shapefile (not the shx!) and see if that fixes things.  These aren't updated by any software other than ArcGIS when they edit shapefiles  which can create issues.  Exporting to a new shapefile or other dataset is another common possible fix.